# A natural result that relativized to a random oracle is true with probability 1/2

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, relativization, random-oracles

There are several well known results regarding random oracles, e.g.

> $\mathsf{IP}^A \neq \mathsf{PSpace}^A$ for almost all oracles.

Are there any known natural examples where a similar statement is both true and false for significant fractions of the random oracles (e.g. it is true with probability $1/2$)?

Comment: No interesting result will depend on the oracle's values on a particular finite set, so this seems to be ruled out by Kolmogorov's zero-one law.

Comment: Expanding on Colin's comment: Let X(A) be a statement about an oracle A. Let A' be any other oracle that differs with A on only finitely many inputs. If you can prove that whenever X(A) is true, X(A') is also true, then Pr(X(A)) is either 0 or 1. Most statements about Turing machines will be true if you modify the oracle at finitely many places, since you can hardcode finitely many values into a Turing machine's internal logic.

Comment: @ColinMcQuillan: that should be an answer :).